# lookup/search values from data frame to create new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to create new column in dataframe based on search of data from other column and row. What is a best/fasted method to calculate such column's value.

I have tried with lambda and external function without result.

1. Can someone elaborate little bit about methods to get final result and which method is optimal from computation time.
2. Can we assign function/lambda which will calculate such values?
3. Can we implement data frame that way it will keep reference to function calculating value in a column rather than calculated values itself? Dynamic result based on data in other columns/rows.

```py
data = { 
            'ID':[1, 2, 3, 4 ,5],                  
            'Name':['Andy', 'Rob', 'Tony', 'John', 'Lui'],
            'M_Name':['Lui', 'Lui', 'Lui','NoData', 'John']
             } 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

Original DataFrame:
    ID  M_Name  Name
0   1     Lui  Andy
1   2     Lui   Rob
2   3     Lui  Tony
3   4  NoData  John
4   5    John   Lui

data_after = { 
            'ID':[1, 2, 3, 4 ,5],                  
            'Name':['Andy', 'Rob', 'Tony', 'John', 'Lui'],
            'M_Name':['Lui', 'Lui', 'Lui','NoData', 'John'],    
            'ID_by_M_Name':[5, 5, 5, 'NoData', '4']
             } 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_after)

Processed DataFrame:
    ID ID_by_M_Name  M_Name  Name
0   1          5     Lui  Andy
1   2          5     Lui   Rob
2   3          5     Lui  Tony
3   4     NoData  NoData  John
4   5          4    John   Lui

I have tried two ways to get ID but not sure how to use them in assign

getID = lambda name: df.loc[df['Name'] == name]['ID'].iloc[0]

def mID(name):
    return df.loc[df['Name'] == name]['ID'].iloc[0]

For each row we want to find ID of M_Name for specifc Name. 
e.g. for Name='Andy' we have M_Name = 'Lui' and Lui's ID(5)
For Lui M_name is John and John's ID is 4

print(getID('Lui'))
print(mID('Lui'))

df['ID'] = df.assign(mID(df['M_Name']), axis=1 )
```

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['ID_by_M_Name'] = df['M_Name'].replace(df.set_index('Name')['ID'])
#assign alternative
#df = df.assign(ID_by_M_Name = df['M_Name'].replace(df.set_index('Name')['ID']))
```

```
df['ID_by_M_Name'] = df['M_Name'].map(df.set_index('Name')['ID']).fillna(df['M_Name'])
#assign alternative
#df=df.assign(ID_by_M_Name=df['M_Name'].map(df.set_index('Name')['ID']).fillna(df['M_Name']))
```

---

```
print (df)

   ID  Name  M_Name ID_by_M_Name
0   1  Andy     Lui            5
1   2   Rob     Lui            5
2   3  Tony     Lui            5
3   4  John  NoData       NoData
4   5   Lui    John            4
```

If important position of new column use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(1, 'ID_by_M_Name', df['M_Name'].replace(df.set_index('Name')['ID']))
print (df)

   ID ID_by_M_Name  Name  M_Name
0   1            5  Andy     Lui
1   2            5   Rob     Lui
2   3            5  Tony     Lui
3   4       NoData  John  NoData
4   5            4   Lui    John
```

Comment: Thanks! I belie replace method is best/simplest based on a new index from data set. How to implement same using external function or lambda?